# Hadoop custom split of TextFile

Tags: hadoop

I have a fairly large text file that I would like to convert into a SequenceFile. Unfortunately, the file consists of Python code with logical lines running over several physical lines. For example,
print "Blah Blah\
... blah blah"
Each logical line is terminated by a NEWLINE. Could someone clarify how I could possibly generate Key, Value pairs in Map-Reduce where each Value is the entire logical line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own variation on TextInputFormat. In there you make a new RecordReader that skips lines until it sees the start of a logical line.

Comment: This is more elegant than what I currently did. I built a local iterable that gave me a logical line and used a RecordReader to transmit the entire document as a ByteWritable. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

I don't find the question asked earlier, but you just have to iterate over your lines via a simple mapreduce job and save them into a StringBuilder. Flush the StringBuilder to the context if you want to begin with a new record. The trick is to setup the StringBuilder in your mappers class as a field and not as a local variable.

here it is:
[Processing paraphragraphs in text files as single records with Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827997/processing-paraphragraphs-in-text-files-as-single-records-with-hadoop/5828705#5828705)

Answer (score 0):

Preprocess the input file to remove the newlines. What is your goal in creating the SequenceFile?